# jQuery Datatables - match filtering words

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery datatables and was hoping someone knew how to do this.

We have items in the database listed as 4x4 and 4wd.  I would like it to also retrieve 4wd when I type in 4x4 and visa versa.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Andy

Comment: if `search filter == 4x4` add another `or` operator for `col_name = '4wd'`

Comment: Hi Vond Ritz, I was wondering where I should implement this code?

Comment: you can do it on your datatables if it's processing on server-side.

Comment: if it's not processing on server-side. MaVRoSCy suggestion will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

One solution will be to have a hidden column (see [bVisible](http://datatables.net/usage/columns)) and add the alternate description in that column. (In your case, where the result is 4x4 then in the hidden column it would be 4wd and the other way around). So when you search you will get both results